# Hide Query parameter along with the value using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I hide query parameter along with its value in the URL
Let's consider this URL

`https://example.com/some-url-structure?price=<some price value>`

I need to hide the price parameter along with the price value in the URL but, the PHP file needs to get the price value.

This price value is sent from another page through header like...

`header(Location: https://example.com/some-url-structure?price=<some price value>);`

So, there's no option of using POST method so that I could hide the price parameter.

Comment: load the price from the server eg. from a database

Comment: try using POST method, else until you use GET method then the value will be visible in url

Comment: Independent whether you can hide that parameter or not: you certainly do _not_ want to rely on a price you get transmitted from the client side! Every user with a basic knowledge of IT will be able to send you any price desirable! _You cannot trust any value you get from the client side_. Period.

Comment: @RolandStarke check my updated question

Comment: @Sasikumar check the updated question

Comment: How do I send those value then @arkascha

Comment: I am sorry to say, but if you really need to transmit that price and have to rely on it blindly for some sort of transaction then your whole architecture is questionable. Whatever you try, _all values submitted from the client side can be manipulated easily_. You want to risk that? I assume not. The only option _might_ be cryptography, but that raises even more questions and security issues than it solves, typically. So I'd like to ask back: _why_ do you have to submit a price from client to server?